# Why doesn't spread radius property for `filter: drop-shadow(...);` work?

Tags: html, css

According to the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow), `filter: drop-shadow(offset-x offset-y blur-radius spread-radius colour)` should work, similar to a normal box-shadow, but when I try it spread-radius doesn't work and as such the style is invalid. Then I thought maybe it was Firefox-specific, but when I checked it there, it was still invalid. Is there a reason why this happens? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: share your real use case, we can always find some workarounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This MDN page is a bit misleading.

While it might come to the specs one day, they [currently state](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#funcdef-filter-drop-shadow) that

> Note: Spread values or multiple shadows are not accepted for this level of the specification.

To put it in context, they say so because the `drop-shadow` filter takes the same parameters has the `box-shadow` one, which does have a [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow#spread-radius) value.

Spreading a `box-shadow` is an easy thing to do, but `drop-shadow` filter can apply on far more complex shapes, so it's harder to implement.

Even [SVG filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Filters_Tutorial) don't have an equivalent, though it might be possible to make something there, with a lot of work.

To the defense of that MDN article, it has a warning box stating

> Most browsers do not support this parameter; the effect will not render if used.

Ps: here is an svg filter generator I made, approximating that. It's not entirely equivalent to what box-shadow's spread does, but it might be enough for some cases.

```js
const filtered = document.getElementById( 'filtered' );
const box_shadow = document.getElementById( 'box_shadow' );
const clipped = document.getElementById( 'clipped' );
inp.onchange = function() {
  filtered.style.borderRadius = this.value;
  box_shadow.style.borderRadius = this.value;
};
inp.onchange();

filtered.style.filter = clipped.style.filter = 'url( #' + spreadingBoxShadow( 20, 20, 10, 50, "blue" ) + ')';

function spreadingBoxShadow( offset_x, offset_y, blur_radius, spread_radius, color ) {

  const _id = "spread-radius-" + Date.now();
  const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
  svg.innerHTML = `
    <filter id="${ _id }" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-color="${ color }" result="flood" in="SourceAlpha" />
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" in="flood" operator="atop" result="color" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="${ spread_radius}" result="spread" in="color"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="spread" stdDeviation="${ blur_radius }" result="shadow"/>
    <feOffset dx="${ offset_x }" dy="${ offset_y }" in="shadow" result="offset"/>
      <feMerge result="merge">
        <feMergeNode in="offset"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
`;
  document.body.append( svg );
  return _id;

}
```

```css
#box_shadow,#filtered,#clipped > div {
  width: 325px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  margin: 30px 50px 100px;
}
#box_shadow {
 box-shadow: 20px 20px 10px 50px blue;
}
#clipped {
  padding: 50px;
}
#clipped > div {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 70% 10%, 70% 80%, 0 40%);
}
.cont {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
Change border-radius here: <input id="inp" value="120px 200px / 100px 0px">
<div class="cont">
  Filter:<br>
  <div id="filtered"></div>
  Box-shadow:<br>
  <div id="box_shadow"></div>
  Clipped:<br>
  <div id="clipped">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't even notice that! Thanks for pointing it out to me. Are there any alternatives for dom elements like buttons with a clip-path? Or is that going to be difficult to implement?

Comment: That will be difficult. Consider an svg path maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow which clearly state that "The drop-shadow() function accepts a parameter of type  (defined in the box-shadow property), with **the exception that the inset keyword and spread parameters are not allowed.**"

Answer (score -1):

MDN have already told you that you're not supported to use it .

> Most browsers do not support this parameter, the effect will not render if used.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzipB.png)